# `ls` fails for directory copied from Win and OSX

Tags: permissions, directory, ls

I'm not able to `ls` on a folder that I have just transferred from win7 to OSX via a FAT32 drive.  I don't know how to search for an answer for this issue.

I've attempted the following:

```
sudo chmod u=rwx myfolder/
sudo chmod a+rx myfolder/
```

...to no avail.
I have found that `sudo ls` seems to work. 
Why would this be?

Comment: Instead of telling something rather useless (due to the general nature of the statement) like "I've attempted to run a disk permissions fix, along with chown" you should tell exactly what you did and what that resulted in.

Comment: Have you copied the folder from the FAT32 volume to an OSX volume (native Unix filesystem) or do you access the folder **on** the FAT32 volume?

Comment: Yes, I've copied it from the FAT32 volume to the OSX volume.

Comment: What error does `ls` return?

Comment: None.  Fails silently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, i would have never thought this could happen, but turns out that there was a file in that directory named 'ls' without an extension, so it was overriding the sys default while i was in that directory and running `ls` via the `cwd`'s supposed executable of it.

a rare and embarrassing case, but true and not completely obvious while attempting to troubleshoot.  i suppose this is one of the oldest issues in the book.

Comment: If that was indeed the problem, it implies you added the current directory (`.`) to your `PATH` environment variable (else you'd have needed to type `./ls` to execute the local file) - that's generally regarded as bad practice, and probably should be removed.

Comment: You had `.` on your path, and had `ls` in the current directory, and it was marked executable, and it actually had contents that were executable?

Answer (score 0):

Probably either read or execute permission (or both) are missing. You can check that with `ls -ld folder`.

You can correct it with `chmod u=rwx folder` or (depending on the intended permissions `chmod a+rx folder`.

Comment: thanks for the tip - neither of these worked.  i've updated my question.